# В выводе проектов не показывается первый проект (bitrix)

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть вывод проектов на карту, но он работает не очень

у меня проблема наверное одна глобальная не выводит первый элемент
кусок кода вот

```
'https://plnkr.co/edit/YaHaFjjul29pcvlTGKiS?p=info'
```

Т.е. если у меня всего 1 элемент он не отображается(
Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

> if (!$BDRes->GetNext())

Не стоит так проверять наличие элементов в выборке, т.к. в этом случае вы получаете первый элемент и затем в цикле начинаете обрабатывать начиная со второго элемента.

Если вам нужно узнать наличие элементов в выборке, используйте метод **[SelectedRowsCount](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cdbresult/selectedrowscount.php%22SelectedRowsCount%22)**, который возвращает количество выбранных записей.